# USB Downstream Port (with Power Charging)

Tags: usb, usb-c, hub

I have a Dell UltraSharp 32 4K USB-C Monitor: U3219Q with a USB Downstream Port (with Power Charging). I have the monitor connected to my laptop via USB-C.

If I connect a USB device (let's say an audio soundcard) on Dell Monitor that does not require power charging, will this be damaged?

Comment: Is it just a regular usb A port? I think this should be no problem. The usb port will supply only the power required for the connected device.

Comment: I think it is USB A yes..

Answer (score 1):

USB-C delivers 5V on its standard configuration and is compatible with previous USB standards.

It will deliver higher voltage only after a power negotiation process done with the device, for USB-C device. So yes you can connect safely any devices on a USB-C port that has power delivery even if the device is not usb-c.